# Inconsistently handled emoji sequences on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, unicode, emoji

On both iOS and macOS, sequences of [regional indicator symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol) are rendered as national flag emoji, and if the sequence is invalid the actual symbols are presented instead:

[image: Plain regional indicator symbols.]

However, if the sequence happens to contain a pair of regional indicator symbols that don't map to a flag emoji, the potential flags are rendered on a first-match basis:

[image: Some funky rendering.]

<sup>iOS/macOS rendering the symbols: F F I S E S.</sup>

In Swift 3, consecutive regional indicator symbols were all lumped into one `Character`, meaning that one `Character` object could contain a theoretically limitless amount of `UnicodeScalar` objects, as long as they were all regional indicator symbols. In essence, Swift 3 didn't break regional indicator symbols at all.

In Swift 4, on the other hand, one `Character` object contains at most two regional indicator symbols in its Unicode scalar representation. Additionally, and understandably, the validity of the sequence isn't considered, so regional indicator symbol sequences are simply broken up at every two scalars and considered a `Character`. Now, iterating the same string as above and printing each character produces the following:

[image: Some other funky rendering.]

<sup>Swift 4 string containing the symbols: F F I S E S.</sup>

Which brings us to the actual question – is the issue with how iOS and macOS renders the sequences, or how Swift 4 constructs the `Character` representation in strings?

I'm curious as to which party would be the most appropriate to report this peculiarity to.

---

Here is a minimal reproducible snippet for the behaviour in Swift 4:

```
// Regional indicator symbols F F I S E S
var string = "\u{1f1eb}\u{1f1eb}\u{1f1ee}\u{1f1f8}\u{1f1ea}\u{1f1f8}"

for character in string {
    print(character)
}
```

Comment: Good find. I think it's an inconsistency between algorithms.

Comment: The behavior still works on a first-match basis. Consider the string `\u{1f19a}\u{1f1eb}\u{1f1ee}\u{1f1f8}\u{1f1ea}\u{1f1f8}`...

Comment: @l'L'l What do you mean with this? `U+1f19a` isn't a regional indicator symbol, so I fail to see how that's relevant with regards to the question.

Comment: And `\u{1f1eb}` by itself is?

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, regional indicator symbols are all code points in the range `U+1F1E6...U+1F1FF`. By themselves they are exactly that, regional indicator symbols, but in a sequence exactly two regional indicator symbols may form a [flag](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-sequences.html#flags).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, although I'm not understanding what the issue is in Swift 4 though. It appears to have the proper behavior, as `FF` wouldn't be valid to form an emoji representation of Africa (not included in ISO 3166-1 afaik).

Comment: @l'L'l Exactly, but it's the inconsistency between the rendering in iOS/macOS and the `Character` representation of the string in Swift 4 which is the main curiosity.

Comment: It looks like in Swift 4 the symbols are represented correctly, whereas previous versions not so much...

Comment: @l'L'l Previous versions of Swift? It's the current versions of iOS and macOS that render the sequences differently than Swift 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears that neither is wrong, although the method implemented in Swift 4 is more true to recommendations.

As per the Unicode standard (emphasis mine):

> The representative glyph for a single regional indicator symbol is just a dotted box containing a capital Latin letter. The Unicode Standard **does not prescribe how the pairs of regional indicator symbols should be rendered**. However, current industry practice widely interprets pairs of regional indicator symbols as representing a flag associated with the corresponding ISO 3166 region code.
>
> – [The Unicode Standard, Version 10.0 – Core Specification](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf), page 836.

Then, on the following page:

> Conformance to the Unicode Standard does not require conformance to UTS #51. However, the interpretation and display of pairs of regional indicator symbols as specified in UTS #51 is now widely deployed, so **in practice it is not advisable to attempt to interpret pairs of regional indicator symbols as representing anything other than an emoji flag**.
>
> – The Unicode Standard, Version 10.0 – Core Specification, page 837.

From this I gather that while the standard doesn't set any rules for how the flags should be rendered, the chosen path for handling the rendering of invalid flag sequences in iOS and macOS is inadvisable. So, even if there exists a valid flag further in the sequence, the renderer should always consider two consecutive regional indicator symbols as a flag.

Finally, taking a look at UTS #51, or "the emoji specification":

> Options for presenting an emoji_flag_sequence for which a system does not have a specific flag or other glyph include:
>
> - **Displaying each REGIONAL INDICATOR symbol separately as a letter in a dotted square, as shown in the Unicode charts**. This provides information about the specific region indicated, but may be mystifying to some users.
> - **For all unsupported REGIONAL INDICATOR pairs, displaying the same “missing flag” glyph, such as the image shown below**. This would indicate that the supported pair was intended to represent the flag of some region, without indicating which one.
>
> > [image: Missing flag glyph.]
>
> – [Unicode Technical Standard #51, revision 12](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-12.html), Annex B.

So, in conclusion, best practice would be representing invalid flag sequences as a pair of regional indicator symbols – exactly as is the case with `Character` objects in Swift 4 strings – or as a generic *missing flag* glyph.